# BuildFire: How do we access the public logs?

Tags: buildfire

We are pushing logs using "buildfire.publicData.insert".  How do we get access to those logs?

Would these logs contain the header that is sent in the calls?  We also need to see the source and destination information.  Those are the logs we really need.

Answer (score 0):

Public data is really just a data source, think of it as a database where the data you save in you can retrieve later.

So if you're using it to push logs you need to make sure that any needed information is in the body object are passed to `save` or `insert` calls. those can be retrieved later using `search` calls as documented in https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/public-data

You can also implement the search only on the control side of your plugin if these data are not meant to be shared with widget users.

Since you might have a lot of records it is recommended you use  https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/indexed-fields so your queries are efficient.